# Approximate Expected Value of Product of Two Random Variables

Tags: expected-value, approximation

I'm looking to find an approximation of $\mathbb{E}\left[ XY \right]$ in terms of $\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right]^n$, $\mathbb{E}\left[ Y \right]^n$, $\mathbb{E}\left[ X^n \right]$, $\mathbb{E}\left[ Y^n \right]$. X and Y have a covariance.

Intuitively, I'd expect the first term would be $\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right] \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \right]$

Comment: Intuitively, nothing like that is possible, because you are asking to find a property of the *joint* distribution based solely on properties of the *marginal* distributions.  It might be possible to develop weak bounds when you have many univariate moments, but that would be difficult and scarcely seems worthwhile.

Comment: That does make sense, thank you. I'll look into for methods to approximating properties of joint distributions

Comment: Bounding via Cauchy Schwarz might provide some results?

Comment: @ChristophHanck That's equivalent to bounding the correlation by the interval $[-1,1].$